# Create a distribution of number of days active in a week. SQL

Tags: sql, distribution

I have a table in SQL that looks like this.

```
Date    CustomerID
1/1        12
1/3        32
1/3        42 
1/4        52
1/4        62  
1/5        75
```

I want to create A distribution of # days active within a week: Create a table to show how many members are active for 1 day, 2days, 3days,…7days during 3/1-3/7.

[Screenshot of desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7Dha.png)

I have written this query. Would it work?

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT date) AS ‘#Days Active’, COUNT(DISTINCT memberID) AS ‘Count’ 
FROM User Table 
WHERE date BETWEEN ‘03/01/17’ AND 03/07/17 
GROUP by COUNT (DISTINCT date) 
ORDER BY COUNT (DISTINCT date) ASC;
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I do not misunderstand you meaning, the code is shown as follows:
it is a two step query:
step1: get the active days for each member
step2: get the member count for each kind of active days.

```
SELECT active_days, count(*) AS member_cnt
  FROM(
       SELECT CustomerID, count(*) AS active_days
         FROM your_table_name
        GROUP BY CustomerID)a
 GROUP BY active_days
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your table has multiple rows per customer. For example customer 12 has one row between input dates, and customer 32 has 3 rows between input dates.

First you need to group by customerId to get activeDayCounts, then group by activeDays to count customer

```
select x.activeDays, count(1) count from (
  select CustomerID, count(1) activeDays from temp
  where Date between '2017-03-01' and '2017-03-07'
  group by CustomerID) x
group by x.activeDays
```

You can check the exmaple with the link https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=19a3187913985faef617d9110730feba